# Using setState inside useEffect on updating forms

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-redux, react-hooks

So I was code-along tutorial on using Forms in React.

**What I intend to do**: Current user navigates to '/update-profile' path ==> parts of form input that user already did before, shows.

**What currently happens**: The API calls to the backend works fine. The profile data stored to the state, but all of the form values shows nothing, even though some parts of it already filled before

I already copy-paste the source file but the problem still occurs, while in the video it works just fine. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
const EditProfile = ({
  profileState: { profile, loading },
  getCurrentProfile
}) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    company: "",
    website: "",
    location: "",
    status: "",
    skills: "",
    bio: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentProfile();

    setFormData({
      company: loading || !profile.company ? "" : profile.company,
      website: loading || !profile.website ? "" : profile.website,
      location: loading || !profile.location ? "" : profile.location,
      status: loading || !profile.status ? "" : profile.status,
      skills: loading || !profile.skills ? "" : profile.skills.join(","),
      bio: loading || !profile.bio ? "" : profile.bio
    });
  }, [loading, getCurrentProfile]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for your backend data and then update your local state. You can use async/await or Promise syntax to do it. Using async/await syntax:

```
useEffect(() => {

        async function getAPI() {
            await getCurrentProfile();
            setFormData({
               company: loading || !profile.company ? "" : profile.company,
               website: loading || !profile.website ? "" : profile.website,
               location: loading || !profile.location ? "" : profile.location,
               status: loading || !profile.status ? "" : profile.status,
               skills: loading || !profile.skills ? "" : profile.skills.join(","),
               bio: loading || !profile.bio ? "" : profile.bio
            });
        }
        getAPI();

    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to split this into 2 effects:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getCurrentProfile();
}, [getCurrentProfile]);

useEffect(() => {
  setFormData({
    company: loading || !profile.company ? "" : profile.company,
    website: loading || !profile.website ? "" : profile.website,
    location: loading || !profile.location ? "" : profile.location,
    status: loading || !profile.status ? "" : profile.status,
    skills: loading || !profile.skills ? "" : profile.skills.join(","),
    bio: loading || !profile.bio ? "" : profile.bio
  });
}, [loading, profile]);
```